# What's Irony's equivalent of Yacc's optional operator ("?")?

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, yacc, irony

I have a fragment of grammar in Yacc notation:

```
stylesheet
: [ CHARSET_SYM STRING ';' ]?
  [S|CDO|CDC]* [ import [ CDO S* | CDC S* ]* ]*
  [ [ ruleset | media | page ] [ CDO S* | CDC S* ]* ]*
;
```

How do I implement this fragment in Irony? I can't find any equivalent of `?`, which means 0 or 1 occurrence in Yacc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `BnfTerm.Q` method to represent **'?'** (0 or 1 occurrences).
This was a reasonable design decision since C# does not let you write a custom implementation of the `?` operator, unlike `+` and `*`.

From the [Non Terminals page](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Irony_-_Language_Implementation_Kit/Grammar/Non_Terminals) on the Irony Wikibook:

> In traditional BNF notation, the "?", "+", and "*" characters are used
>   to indicate "0 or 1 time", "1 or more times" and "0 or more times",
>   respectively. In Irony, it's done slightly differently. You use the
>   MakePlusRule and MakeStarRule methods from the base Grammar class for
>   "+" and "*" or you can use the Q(), Plus(), and Star() methods
>   directly on the term within the rule.

Comment: The Q, Plus and Star methods on terms were deprecated around 2010 and have been removed at some point since then. What is the alternative to Q?

Answer (score 1):

The author says an additional AST node is now required for this purpose.
So for example you could substitute the following for an optional term in a rule:

```
new NonTerminal("OptionalTermName", Empty | TermThatShouldBeOptional)
```

http://irony.codeplex.com/discussions/550979

I wonder if it could be reduced to:

```
(Empty | TermThatShouldBeOptional)
```

The overload creates a BNF Term, rather than a NonTerminal node, which could lose some hierarchical information when joined directly with other BNF terms, depending on the implementation. I haven't investigated further.